# Matlab: Specify Range of Values to be colored in Surf-Plot

Tags: matlab, colors, plot, surface

I am plotting a 3D graph in Matlab using `surf`. The values of the the z axis are between `0` and `0.3`. I do not want the zeros to be colored. They are supposed to be white. How can I do this?

Comment: How do you have that 3D data? As a 3D array or separate x, y and z's?

Comment: I have it as separate x,y and z's.

Comment: And you don't want the points where `z = 0` to be colored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the points where `z = 0` as `NaNs` for all `X`, `Y` and `Z` and those points won't show up in the plot, i.e. they would be "not-colored". So you can do this -

```
X(Z==0) = NaN
Y(Z==0) = NaN
Z(Z==0) = NaN

surf(X,Y,Z);
```

But, be careful about floating point precision issues, as you are comparing against an absolute zero value.

With floating point cases, you can use a tolerance value -

```
tol = 0.08; %// tolerance

X(abs(Z)<tol) = NaN
Y(abs(Z)<tol) = NaN
Z(abs(Z)<tol) = NaN

surf(X,Y,Z);
```

---

### Example

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks(25)

figure,surf(X,Y,Z), title('BEFORE')

tol = 0.08; %// tolerance

X(abs(Z)<tol) = NaN;
Y(abs(Z)<tol) = NaN;
Z(abs(Z)<tol) = NaN;

figure,surf(X,Y,Z), title('AFTER')
```

Results -

[image]

[image]

Comment: @user3170559 Glad to hear that! Was a good question too! Cheers.

Comment: Is it possible to set the remaining values to the same color?